# i am getting error : fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found while installing mongodb in mac m1 for the laravel project

Tags: macos, mongodb

```
 nssl.c:24:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
 #include <openssl/sha.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1 error generated.
 make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.lo] Error 1
 ERROR: `make' failed
```

my OS Details are :

```
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.3
BuildVersion:       23D56

unix variant
local 23.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.3.0: Wed Dec 20 21:30:27 PST 2023; root:xnu-10002.81.5~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 x86_64

php version : PHP 8.2.4
```

I issued the terminal command: `sudo pecl install mongodb`

this is from this site :
[MongoDB PHP Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php-drivers/)

where my install has stopped with this error:

```
 nssl.c:24:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
 #include <openssl/sha.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1 error generated.
 make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.lo] Error 1
 ERROR: `make' failed
```

I found the work around below from: [Mac OSX fatal error: ‘openssl/sha.h’ file not found](https://www.anintegratedworld.com/mac-osx-fatal-error-opensslsha-h-file-not-found/#comments)

```
cd /usr/local/include 
ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl .
```

Quoting a Comment:

> Apple deprecated its OpenSSL shared libraries a while back (with OS X 10.7). That’s because OpenSSL doesn’t offer release-to-release binary compatibility, so we can’t update the shared libraries to the latest OpenSSL without breaking all the existing clients.

but i even don't have include folder in my mac ... please help

I got the path to openssl by doing `which openssl` in terminal -
`/opt/homebrew/bin/openssl`

doing

```
    % ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/openssl 

    lrwxr-xr-x  1 janammaharjan  admin  37 Feb  7 22:12 
    /opt/homebrew/bin/openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.1/bin/openssl
```

Comment: I further edited your question in hopes of helping.  While prettifying the links for that quoted comment, I noticed that the entire post was recommending to install the Homebrew Packaged version of OpenSSL.  Have you done that, and you're still stuck with the homebrew version, or did you skip the post right to the comment in favor of a quick fix?

Comment: @eyoung100 thank you.. yeah tried to install homebrew version of openssl but still same error .. i have tried to change version from  to openssl 3.2.1 to openssl@1.1.but i am still facing same error

Comment: Please add the output of a listing for your Homebrew OpenSSL install, most likely `ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl/3.21/` to your question details

Comment: when i did "which openssl" in terminal it gave me : /opt/homebrew/bin/openssl

Comment: doing % ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/openssl 
...gave me 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 janammaharjan  admin  37 Feb  7 22:12 /opt/homebrew/bin/openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.1/bin/openssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Proper Solution

Let's start over and use an official install method for PHP, Laravel, and the MongoDB Extension.  After all this you should have a working native MAMP server for Development.

---

### Steps

These steps assume we want to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) natively for everything we need in our Development Environment, while keeping the macOS versions of the needed tools pristine.

1. Install Homebrew (for completeness sake, you've already done this):

   - `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` - *One liner*
2. Install Node.js/npm:

   - `brew install node`
3. Install newest PHP in Homebrew's repository:

   - `brew install php` - *If you need a different version use the set identifier `@`. EX: `brew install php@8.1`*
4. Install Composer for dependency management:

   - `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` - *One Liner*
5. Verify Installation

   - `php --version composer --version`
6. Install Laravel - This will be managed by Composer, and shouldn't affect daily use:

   - `composer global require laravel/installer`
7. Create an empty Project:

   - `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <app-name>` - **Be sure to replace app-name with the name of your project**.
8. Verify the Project Starts

   - `php artisan serve` - *Check your browser at whatever IP Address you have setup on port 8000*

Reference: [How To Install Laravel on macOS](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/install-laravel/#how-to-install-laravel-on-macos)

The above steps ensure this answer and your question, are now starting in the same place:

### Add MongoDB

Quoting from the [MongoDB Docs: Install the MongoDB PHP Library](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/tutorial/install-php-library/):

> Note:
>
> If the build process for either installation method fails to find a TLS library, check that the development packages (e.g. libssl-dev) and
> pkg-config are both installed.

Since you're question references this note, let's fix it with:

1. `brew install libssl-dev && brew install pkg-config`

### Explanation

The `libssl-dev` package contains the missing header file. The `pkg config` package/script when installed in the Homebrew Cellar will search for Libraries for packages also installed in the Cellar.  **It will not report a library path outside of Homebrew back to make**.  After installing these 2 packages, the `pecl` command should complete as per [MongoDB Laravel Integration](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-laravel-integration)

Comment: Thank you very much . saved me.. very grateful after two days of search finally it is installed.
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/mongodb.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.17.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini